# Unable to get squid working on centos

Tags: centos, squid

I have set up squid on my centos vps server and I am trying to connect to it through my windows computer but I am getting following error for all the websites:

> Waiting for google.com
>
> The proxy server isn't responding

I have followed the following tutorial to set up squid:

[How To Install Squid Proxy on CentOS 6](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-squid-proxy-on-centos-6)

My squid conf file:

```
#
# Recommended minimum configuration:
#
acl manager proto cache_object
acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/32 ::1
acl to_localhost dst 127.0.0.0/8 0.0.0.0/32 ::1

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt to list your (internal) IP networks from where browsing
# should be allowed
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8 # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12  # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16 # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src fc00::/7       # RFC 4193 local private network range
acl localnet src fe80::/10      # RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged) machines

acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80      # http
acl Safe_ports port 21      # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443     # https
acl Safe_ports port 70      # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210     # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280     # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488     # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591     # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777     # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

#
# Recommended minimum Access Permission configuration:
#
# Only allow cachemgr access from localhost
http_access allow manager localhost
http_access deny manager

# Deny requests to certain unsafe ports
http_access deny !Safe_ports

# Deny CONNECT to other than secure SSL ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports

# We strongly recommend the following be uncommented to protect innocent
# web applications running on the proxy server who think the only
# one who can access services on "localhost" is a local user
#http_access deny to_localhost

#
# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE(S) HERE TO ALLOW ACCESS FROM YOUR CLIENTS
#

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt localnet in the ACL section to list your (internal) IP networks
# from where browsing should be allowed
http_access allow localnet
http_access allow localhost
http_access allow all

# And finally deny all other access to this proxy
# http_access deny all

# Squid normally listens to port 3128
http_port 3128

# We recommend you to use at least the following line.
hierarchy_stoplist cgi-bin ?

# Uncomment and adjust the following to add a disk cache directory.
#cache_dir ufs /var/spool/squid 100 16 256

# Leave coredumps in the first cache dir
coredump_dir /var/spool/squid

# Add any of your own refresh_pattern entries above these.
refresh_pattern ^ftp:       1440    20% 10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:    1440    0%  1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0 0%  0
refresh_pattern .       0   20% 4320

visible_hostname myproxy
```

Thanks.

Update :

Access log:

```
1431455471.946   1136 61.160.213.33 TCP_MISS/200 654 GET http://zc.qq.com/cgi-bin/chs/numreg/init? - DIRECT/163.177.56.115 application/json
1431455540.816    711 104.217.55.135 TCP_MISS/200 321 GET http://zc.qq.com/chs/ver.js? - DIRECT/163.177.56.115 application/x-javascript
1431455567.306   1901 118.193.158.165 TCP_MISS/200 296 POST http://zc.qq.com/cgi-bin/en/othmailreg/get_acc? - DIRECT/163.177.56.115 text/html
1431455569.419   1813 118.193.158.165 TCP_MISS/302 401 GET http://zc.qq.com:443/cgi-bin/common/new_router - DIRECT/163.177.56.115 text/html
1431455571.911   1731 118.193.158.165 TCP_MISS/200 321 GET http://zc.qq.com/en/ver.js? - DIRECT/163.177.56.115 application/x-javascript
1431455573.040    812 118.193.158.165 TCP_MISS/200 650 GET http://zc.qq.com/cgi-bin/en/othmailreg/init? - DIRECT/163.177.56.115 text/html
1431455574.177    402 118.193.158.165 TCP_MISS/200 278 GET http://zc.qq.com/cgi-bin/common/attr? - DIRECT/163.177.56.115 text/html
1431455575.491    995 118.193.158.165 TCP_MISS/200 1172 GET http://a.zc.qq.com/s.js? - DIRECT/112.90.140.50 application/x-javascript
1431455576.624    814 118.193.158.165 TCP_MISS/200 278 GET http://zc.qq.com/cgi-bin/common/attr? - DIRECT/163.177.56.115 text/html
1431455577.335    404 118.193.158.165 TCP_MISS/200 278 GET http://zc.qq.com/cgi-bin/common/attr? - DIRECT/163.177.56.115 text/html
1431455578.508    817 118.193.158.165 TCP_MISS/200 278 GET http://zc.qq.com/cgi-bin/common/attr? - DIRECT/163.177.56.115 text/html
1431455580.627   1630 118.193.158.165 TCP_MISS/200 3337 GET http://captcha.qq.com/getimage? - DIRECT/112.90.83.73 image/jpeg
1431455581.868    420 118.193.158.165 TCP_MISS/200 277 GET http://zc.qq.com/cgi-bin/common/attr? - DIRECT/163.177.56.115 text/html
1431455582.878    679 118.193.158.165 TCP_MISS/200 248 GET http://a.zc.qq.com/Cgi-bin/SecCheck? - DIRECT/112.90.140.50 text/html
1431455583.736    415 118.193.158.165 TCP_MISS/200 1859 GET http://zc.qq.com/en/m.js? - DIRECT/163.177.56.115 application/x-javascript
1431455584.449    416 118.193.158.165 TCP_MISS/200 407 GET http://zc.qq.com/cgi-bin/en/qqmailreg/init? - DIRECT/163.177.56.115 text/html
1431455585.157    411 118.193.158.165 TCP_MISS/200 278 GET http://zc.qq.com/cgi-bin/common/attr? - DIRECT/163.177.56.115 text/html
1431455586.884   1313 118.193.158.165 TCP_MISS/200 3190 GET http://captcha.qq.com/getimage? - DIRECT/112.90.83.73 image/jpeg
1431455592.194    426 118.193.158.165 TCP_MISS/200 263 GET http://zc.qq.com/cgi-bin/en/qqmailreg/check_mail? - DIRECT/163.177.56.115 text/html
1431455602.604    720 118.193.158.165 TCP_MISS/200 248 GET http://a.zc.qq.com/Cgi-bin/MoniKey? - DIRECT/112.90.140.50 text/html
1431455604.194   1183 118.193.158.165 TCP_MISS/200 3292 GET http://captcha.qq.com/getimage? - DIRECT/112.90.83.73 image/jpeg
1431455605.522    417 118.193.158.165 TCP_MISS/200 263 GET http://zc.qq.com/cgi-bin/en/common/dirty_check? - DIRECT/163.177.56.115 text/html
1431455614.890    725 118.193.158.165 TCP_MISS/200 248 GET http://a.zc.qq.com/Cgi-bin/MoniKey? - DIRECT/112.90.140.50 text/html
1431455625.578    708 118.193.158.165 TCP_MISS/200 248 GET http://a.zc.qq.com/Cgi-bin/MoniKey? - DIRECT/112.90.140.50 text/html
1431455636.193    671 118.193.158.165 TCP_MISS/200 248 GET http://a.zc.qq.com/Cgi-bin/MoniKey? - DIRECT/112.90.140.50 text/html
1431455638.130    699 118.193.158.165 TCP_MISS/200 248 GET http://a.zc.qq.com/Cgi-bin/MoniKey? - DIRECT/112.90.140.50 text/html
1431455640.090    772 118.193.158.165 TCP_MISS/200 248 GET http://a.zc.qq.com/Cgi-bin/MoniKey? - DIRECT/112.90.140.50 text/html
1431455642.064    698 118.193.158.165 TCP_MISS/200 248 GET http://a.zc.qq.com/Cgi-bin/MoniKey? - DIRECT/112.90.140.50 text/html
1431455643.987    716 118.193.158.165 TCP_MISS/200 248 GET http://a.zc.qq.com/Cgi-bin/MoniKey? - DIRECT/112.90.140.50 text/html
1431455645.950    691 118.193.158.165 TCP_MISS/200 248 GET http://a.zc.qq.com/Cgi-bin/MoniKey? - DIRECT/112.90.140.50 text/html
1431455648.077    686 118.193.158.165 TCP_MISS/200 248 GET http://a.zc.qq.com/Cgi-bin/MoniKey? - DIRECT/112.90.140.50 text/html
1431455649.761    688 118.193.158.165 TCP_MISS/200 248 GET http://a.zc.qq.com/Cgi-bin/MoniKey? - DIRECT/112.90.140.50 text/html
1431455651.738    804 118.193.158.165 TCP_MISS/200 248 GET http://a.zc.qq.com/Cgi-bin/MoniKey? - DIRECT/112.90.140.50 text/html
1431455653.636    825 118.193.158.165 TCP_MISS/200 248 GET http://a.zc.qq.com/Cgi-bin/MoniKey? - DIRECT/112.90.140.50 text/html
1431455655.591    705 118.193.158.165 TCP_MISS/200 248 GET http://a.zc.qq.com/Cgi-bin/MoniKey? - DIRECT/112.90.140.50 text/html
1431455664.751    682 118.193.158.165 TCP_MISS/200 248 GET http://a.zc.qq.com/Cgi-bin/MoniKey? - DIRECT/112.90.140.50 text/html
1431455670.522   5242 118.193.158.165 TCP_MISS/200 1608 POST http://zc.qq.com/cgi-bin/en/qqmailreg/get_acc? - DIRECT/163.177.56.115 text/html
1431455922.382   1333 222.172.93.221 TCP_MISS/200 513 GET http://zc.qq.com/cgi-bin/chs/numreg/init? - DIRECT/163.177.56.115 application/json
1431456134.184   1248 61.160.213.33 TCP_MISS/200 654 GET http://zc.qq.com/cgi-bin/chs/numreg/init? - DIRECT/163.177.56.115 application/json
1431456182.329    745 59.174.88.27 TCP_MISS/200 513 GET http://zc.qq.com/cgi-bin/chs/numreg/init? - DIRECT/163.177.56.115 application/json
```

Cache Log:

```
2015/05/12 14:24:46| Loaded Icons.
2015/05/12 14:24:46| Accepting  HTTP connections at [::]:3128, FD 14.
2015/05/12 14:24:46| HTCP Disabled.
2015/05/12 14:24:46| WARNING: 'myproxy' rDNS test failed: (14) Bad address
2015/05/12 14:24:46| WARNING: Could not determine this machines public hostname. Please configure one or set 'visible_hostname'.
2015/05/12 14:24:46| Squid plugin modules loaded: 0
2015/05/12 14:24:46| Adaptation support is off.
2015/05/12 14:24:46| Ready to serve requests.
2015/05/12 14:24:47| storeLateRelease: released 0 objects
2015/05/12 14:26:00| Preparing for shutdown after 0 requests
2015/05/12 14:26:00| Waiting 30 seconds for active connections to finish
2015/05/12 14:26:00| FD 14 Closing HTTP connection
2015/05/12 14:26:31| Shutting down...
2015/05/12 14:26:31| basic/auth_basic.cc(97) done: Basic authentication Shutdown.
2015/05/12 14:26:31| Closing unlinkd pipe on FD 13
2015/05/12 14:26:31| storeDirWriteCleanLogs: Starting...
2015/05/12 14:26:31|   Finished.  Wrote 0 entries.
2015/05/12 14:26:31|   Took 0.00 seconds (  0.00 entries/sec).
CPU Usage: 0.097 seconds = 0.046 user + 0.051 sys
Maximum Resident Size: 42272 KB
Page faults with physical i/o: 0
Memory usage for squid via mallinfo():
    total space in arena:    3528 KB
    Ordinary blocks:         3501 KB      4 blks
    Small blocks:               0 KB      6 blks
    Holding blocks:          1096 KB      4 blks
    Free Small blocks:          0 KB
    Free Ordinary blocks:      26 KB
    Total in use:            4597 KB 130%
    Total free:                27 KB 1%
2015/05/12 14:26:31| Open FD UNSTARTED     7 DNS Socket IPv6
2015/05/12 14:26:31| Open FD UNSTARTED     8 DNS Socket IPv4
2015/05/12 14:26:31| Squid Cache (Version 3.1.10): Exiting normally.
2015/05/12 14:26:32| Starting Squid Cache version 3.1.10 for x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu...
2015/05/12 14:26:32| Process ID 1233
2015/05/12 14:26:32| With 1024 file descriptors available
2015/05/12 14:26:32| Initializing IP Cache...
2015/05/12 14:26:32| DNS Socket created at [::], FD 7
2015/05/12 14:26:32| DNS Socket created at 0.0.0.0, FD 8
2015/05/12 14:26:32| Adding nameserver 8.8.4.4 from /etc/resolv.conf
2015/05/12 14:26:32| Adding nameserver 8.8.8.8 from /etc/resolv.conf
2015/05/12 14:26:32| Adding nameserver 209.244.0.3 from /etc/resolv.conf
2015/05/12 14:26:32| User-Agent logging is disabled.
2015/05/12 14:26:32| Referer logging is disabled.
2015/05/12 14:26:32| Unlinkd pipe opened on FD 13
2015/05/12 14:26:32| Local cache digest enabled; rebuild/rewrite every 3600/3600 sec
2015/05/12 14:26:32| Store logging disabled
2015/05/12 14:26:32| Swap maxSize 0 + 262144 KB, estimated 20164 objects
2015/05/12 14:26:32| Target number of buckets: 1008
2015/05/12 14:26:32| Using 8192 Store buckets
2015/05/12 14:26:32| Max Mem  size: 262144 KB
2015/05/12 14:26:32| Max Swap size: 0 KB
2015/05/12 14:26:32| Using Least Load store dir selection
2015/05/12 14:26:32| Set Current Directory to /var/spool/squid
2015/05/12 14:26:32| Loaded Icons.
2015/05/12 14:26:32| Accepting  HTTP connections at [::]:3128, FD 14.
2015/05/12 14:26:32| HTCP Disabled.
2015/05/12 14:26:32| Squid plugin modules loaded: 0
2015/05/12 14:26:32| Adaptation support is off.
2015/05/12 14:26:32| Ready to serve requests.
2015/05/12 14:26:33| storeLateRelease: released 0 objects
2015/05/12 14:40:38| Preparing for shutdown after 38 requests
2015/05/12 14:40:38| Waiting 30 seconds for active connections to finish
2015/05/12 14:40:38| FD 14 Closing HTTP connection
2015/05/12 14:41:10| Shutting down...
2015/05/12 14:41:10| basic/auth_basic.cc(97) done: Basic authentication Shutdown.
2015/05/12 14:41:10| Closing unlinkd pipe on FD 13
2015/05/12 14:41:10| storeDirWriteCleanLogs: Starting...
2015/05/12 14:41:10|   Finished.  Wrote 0 entries.
2015/05/12 14:41:10|   Took 0.00 seconds (  0.00 entries/sec).
CPU Usage: 0.289 seconds = 0.167 user + 0.122 sys
Maximum Resident Size: 43312 KB
Page faults with physical i/o: 0
Memory usage for squid via mallinfo():
    total space in arena:    3644 KB
    Ordinary blocks:         3604 KB     19 blks
    Small blocks:               0 KB      6 blks
    Holding blocks:          1096 KB      4 blks
    Free Small blocks:          0 KB
    Free Ordinary blocks:      39 KB
    Total in use:            4700 KB 129%
    Total free:                39 KB 1%
2015/05/12 14:41:10| Open FD UNSTARTED     7 DNS Socket IPv6
2015/05/12 14:41:10| Open FD READ/WRITE    8 DNS Socket IPv4
2015/05/12 14:41:10| Squid Cache (Version 3.1.10): Exiting normally.
2015/05/12 14:41:10| Starting Squid Cache version 3.1.10 for x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu...
2015/05/12 14:41:10| Process ID 1279
2015/05/12 14:41:10| With 1024 file descriptors available
2015/05/12 14:41:10| Initializing IP Cache...
2015/05/12 14:41:10| DNS Socket created at [::], FD 7
2015/05/12 14:41:10| DNS Socket created at 0.0.0.0, FD 8
2015/05/12 14:41:10| Adding nameserver 8.8.4.4 from /etc/resolv.conf
2015/05/12 14:41:10| Adding nameserver 8.8.8.8 from /etc/resolv.conf
2015/05/12 14:41:10| Adding nameserver 209.244.0.3 from /etc/resolv.conf
2015/05/12 14:41:10| User-Agent logging is disabled.
2015/05/12 14:41:10| Referer logging is disabled.
2015/05/12 14:41:10| Unlinkd pipe opened on FD 13
2015/05/12 14:41:10| Local cache digest enabled; rebuild/rewrite every 3600/3600 sec
2015/05/12 14:41:10| Store logging disabled
2015/05/12 14:41:10| Swap maxSize 0 + 262144 KB, estimated 20164 objects
2015/05/12 14:41:10| Target number of buckets: 1008
2015/05/12 14:41:10| Using 8192 Store buckets
2015/05/12 14:41:10| Max Mem  size: 262144 KB
2015/05/12 14:41:10| Max Swap size: 0 KB
2015/05/12 14:41:10| Using Least Load store dir selection
2015/05/12 14:41:10| Set Current Directory to /var/spool/squid
2015/05/12 14:41:10| Loaded Icons.
2015/05/12 14:41:10| Accepting  HTTP connections at [::]:3128, FD 14.
2015/05/12 14:41:10| HTCP Disabled.
2015/05/12 14:41:10| Squid plugin modules loaded: 0
2015/05/12 14:41:10| Adaptation support is off.
2015/05/12 14:41:10| Ready to serve requests.
2015/05/12 14:41:11| storeLateRelease: released 0 objects
```

netstat -nltap | grep LIS output :

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                                          ESTABLISHED 1112/sshd
tcp        0      0 :::22                       :::*                        LISTEN      933/sshd
tcp        0      0 :::3128                     :::*                        LISTEN      1279/(squid)
tcp        0      0 ::1:25                      :::*                        LISTEN      1010/master
```

Comment: Please post the squid log for the relevant timeperiod.

Comment: added log files @EEAA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check a few more things other than the log

1. local firewall (iptables)
2. is squid listening on the external ip that other server can access?
   `netstat -nltap | grep LIS`
3. (like 1), use nc or telnet to verify that you can access from a client the default `squid port 3128`. `telnet squidserver 3128`, any response?

Comment: for 3. I get "Could not open connection to host, on port 3128: Connect failed"

Comment: added output of 2 in op

Comment: disabled firewall still not working; even telnet not connecting

Comment: looks like it is listening to ipv6.

Comment: i think you can use http_port ipv4_ip:3128 to explicitly listen to ipv4

Comment: still nothing after updating http_port cant understand why even telnet is not working even after disabling filewall

Comment: check if there is any selinux (or other app security measures) issues by checking /var/log/audit. then try to access the port in the localhost. then the same subnet, etc. to do some network troubleshooting. without knowing you actual setup it is hard at this point for me to suggest more. good luck!

Comment: Thanks I got it working. My ISP was blocking port 3128 once I changed the port it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If port is blocked:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 3128 -j ACCEPT 
iptables-save > /etc/sysconfig/iptables
```

I got the idea from Bitrix Virtual Appliance:

https://training.bitrix24.com/support/training/course/?COURSE_ID=113&LESSON_ID=19986